# Run AS400 stored procedure from C# throw an error

Tags: c#, database, stored-procedures, db2, ibm-midrange

I am trying to run a stored procedure from my code and I am getting the following error:

> Additional information: ERROR [42S02] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]
>   SQL0204 - StoredProc1 in MyLibrary type *FILE not found.

My code:

```
internal DataTable Retrieve()
{
        var sql = string.Format("Select * from StoredProc1");
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
        OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(sql);

        // MyConnectionString = "ODBC;DATABASE=MyLibrary;DSN=AS400-MyLibrary;UID=MyUser;PWD=MyPwd;ALLOWUNSCHAR=0;"
        // It works fine for sure since I can change the StoredProc1 to a table instead and the query works fine. So it is not a connection problem.
        command.Connection = _libraryConnection.Connection;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(command);

        lock (_anyObj)
        {
            _libraryConnection.OpenConnection();
            adapter.Fill(dataset);                
            _libraryConnection.CloseConnection();
        }

        return dataset.Tables[0];
}
```

AS400 stored procedure SQL:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE C2 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR

SELECT * FROM MyLibrary.TABLE1;

OPEN C2 ;
END
```

AS400 options for the stored procedure:

```
Max number of result sets: 0
Data access: Read SQL Data
Concurrent access resolution: Default
Transaction control: Do not commit on return
Unified debugger mode: Disallow debug mode
```

AS400 version 7 release 1

EDITED:
I changed the sql variable as following:

```
var sql = "{CALL StoredProc1()}";
```

Now it is not throwing exception but in other hand I do not get any rows in the datatable. The queried table contains records for sure.

Comment: look for your connection string.  The filename is wrong.  You didn't post the code where the connection string is located.

Comment: Check the stored procedure to see if it calls a file.

Comment: I am not clear, can you explain?

Comment: You show `AS400 options for the stored procedure` in your question. Where does that come from? Are you using Data Studio or some other client to see those options? The first option says `Max number of result sets: 0`. So it seems that there is no `result set` defined. Can you show the creation attributes from the CREATE PROCEDURE statement?

Answer (score 0):

Look in database for the procudure : StoredProc1.  It is opening a file that doesn't exist.

Comment: The query is a simple select * from MyLibrary.TABLE1;
And TABLE1 exists for sure

Comment: Go back to original SQL.  The problem is not with your VS application.  The problems is in the database procedure.

Comment: So what is your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

To make it works, need to do as following:

2 different connection options:

Using ODBC Connection

```
internal DataTable Retrieve()
{
    var sql = "CALL STOREDPROC1()";  // THOSE ARE THE POSSIBLE SYNTHAXES
                                    // OR var sql = "{CALL STOREDPROC1()}";
    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
    OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(sql);

    command.Connection = _libraryConnection.Connection;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandTimeout = 0;  // OPTIONAL

    OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(command);

    lock (_anyObj)
    {
        _libraryConnection.OpenConnection();
        adapter.Fill(dataset);                
        _libraryConnection.CloseConnection();
    }

    return dataset.Tables[0];
```

}

Using ADODB Connection

```
internal DataTable Retrieve()
{
    var sql = "STOREDPROC1()";  // THIS IS THE SYNTHAX
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter= new OleDbDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    ADODB.Command command = new ADODB.Command();
    ADODB.Recordset rs = new ADODB.Recordset();

    command.ActiveConnection = _libraryConnection.Connection;
    command.CommandType = ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdStoredProc;
    command.CommandText = sql;
    command.CommandTimeout = 0;  // OPTIONAL

    rs.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseServer;

    lock (_anyObj)
    {
        rs.Source = command;
        rs.Open();
        adapter.Fill(dt, rs);
        rs.Close();
    }       

    return dt;
```

}

AS400 options for the stored procedure:

```
Max number of result sets: 1
Data access: Read SQL Data
Concurrent access resolution: Default
Transaction control: Do not commit on return
Unified debugger mode: Disallow debug mode
```